# changing the background of element A when hovering over element B - mouseleave not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the background of element A when hovering over element B, and changing it back upon mouseleave. B is a descendant of A. The mouseenter part seems to be working fine (background color changes upon hover), but the mouseleave does not work - the background stays the same.

The HTML:

```
   <div class="A" style="height: 500px; background:blue">
   <div class="B" style="height:400px; width:100px"><img src="someimg.jpg" style="height:400px"></div>
   </div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.B').mouseenter(function(){
$('.A').css('background', 'black');
 });
$('B').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.A').css('background', 'blue');
});
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $('.B').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.A').css('background', 'blue');

you forgot the "." in front of B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add the `.B`

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.B').mouseenter(function(){
$('.A').css('background', 'black');
 });
$('.B').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.A').css('background', 'blue');
});
});
```

Comment: omg silly me! I went over it several times and totally failed to see that I forgot the dot. thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, there is a more elegant solution.

```
$('.B').hover(function() {
    $('.A').css('background', 'black');
}, function() {
    $('.A').css('background', 'blue');
});
```